ip pbx separate data and voice private networks
Recently my ISP decided to force all voip traffic to go through one private network (192.168.2.x) and data through another (192.168.1.x). The result is that my previous setup in which I used a small grandstream ip bpx now does not work because all voip traffic goes through that new network that it cannot see.
Can I somehow combine them using vlans with a level 2 switch?
I do not have admin access to the ISP router, only user-level which is basically useless besides restarting the router and do basic stuff like port mapping and setting up the wifi.
Thanks in advance!

why cant you plug the grandstream directly into the VOIP vlan ,  why do you need it on your data vlan?
